# cross table subtraction with a "where" clause

Tags: ms-access

I have a number of table in my Access database. One of the tables is called `tblCurrentSale` and another is called `TblDraughtStock`.

The current sales table has the following layout:

```
CurrSaleID| DraughtID| SpiritID| SoftDrinkID| BottleID| Item    | SalePrice|
22________|_________1|_________|____________|_________|_Clsbrg__|______2.70|
```

etc...

`TblDraughtStock` looks as follows:

```
DraughtStockID | DraughtID | Item   | Stock |  MinLevelStock |
1______________|_________1_|Clsbrg__|_5000__|___________500__|
```

I need some VBA or SQL that will subtract 1 from the stock column in `TblDraughtStock` when the `draughtID` is the same in both `tblcurrentsale` and `tblDraughtStock`.

Comment: Are you using Access 2010? If not, are you controlling data through forms?

Comment: I'm using access 2010. im using a form and when the button to complete a sale is pressed, the current sales table is copied to the total sales table, the current sales table is emptied. I want the above to happen before the table is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Stock control is inclined to be complicated. A data macro might be a possibility but you are probably better off just running some SQL on the same button click that performs the copy and delete. Very roughly:

```
sSQL = "UPDATE TblDraughtStock t " _
  & "INNER JOIN tblCurrentSale c " _
  & "ON t.DraughtID = c.DraughtID " _
  & "SET t.Stock = t.Stock - 1"

Set db = CurrentDB
db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: So In the Draught Stock Table there are numerous drinks. i have carlsburg pint, carlsburg halp, fosters etc...  

Could I use what you have there as a framework to have a really long SQL statement that would cover each of the drinks (12 types) each of the drinks. having the half pints minus 0.5 from the total

Thanks

Comment: Really long SQL statements are nearly always a bad sign. What you should do is post actual data and a more detailed note what you want to happen.